# How to config Wildfly cluster on google cloud instance

Tags: cloud, cluster-computing, google-cloud-platform, wildfly

I have issue on google cloud platform.
I try POC in VM it good can cluster normally.

but in google cloud platform. can't join cluster with JGROUP in wildfly
I have 2 instance both install Centos 7 and wildfly 10.1.0 final on domain mode.
I setting follow : https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/WildFly+9+Cluster+Howto

```
    2017-03-20 09:44:54,068 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [master:master01|0] (1) [master:master01]
2017-03-20 09:44:54,069 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-8) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel hibernate: [master:master01|0] (1) [master:master01]
2017-03-20 09:44:54,074 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-8) ISPN000079: Channel hibernate local address is master:master01, physical addresses are [127.0.0.1:55200]
2017-03-20 09:44:54,085 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel server: [master:master01|0] (1) [master:master01]
2017-03-20 09:44:54,085 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000079: Channel server local address is master:master01, physical addresses are [127.0.0.1:55200]
2017-03-20 09:44:54,086 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000079: Channel ejb local address is master:master01, physical addresses are [127.0.0.1:55200]
2017-03-20 09:44:54,085 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel web: [master:master01|0] (1) [master:master01]
2017-03-20 09:44:54,088 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000079: Channel web local address is master:master01, physical addresses are [127.0.0.1:55200]
```

slave

```
2017-03-20 11:21:51,701 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel web: [sctha1:master02|0] (1) [sctha1:master02]
2017-03-20 11:21:51,701 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel hibernate: [sctha1:master02|0] (1) [sctha1:master02]
2017-03-20 11:21:51,702 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [sctha1:master02|0] (1) [sctha1:master02]
2017-03-20 11:21:51,703 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-7) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel server: [sctha1:master02|0] (1) [sctha1:master02]
2017-03-20 11:21:51,709 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000079: Channel hibernate local address is sctha1:master02, physical addresses are [10.140.0.2:55200]
2017-03-20 11:21:51,710 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000079: Channel ejb local address is sctha1:master02, physical addresses are [10.140.0.2:55200]
2017-03-20 11:21:51,710 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-7) ISPN000079: Channel server local address is sctha1:master02, physical addresses are [10.140.0.2:55200]
2017-03-20 11:21:51,711 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000079: Channel web local address is sctha1:master02, physical addresses are [10.140.0.2:55200]
```

firewall is disable.

Any one have same issue?

Comment: Take a look https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/02/JGroups-based-clustering-and-node-discovery-with-Google-Cloud-Storage.html

Comment: Thank @FedericoSierra I found solution
https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/WildFly_Clustering_without_Multicast

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because JGroups is set to use private interface (127.0.0.1) by default. In `standalone-ha.xml` you'll find:

```
<socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" interface="private" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
```

Change that attribute to `public` and be sure WildFly is bound to the right interface (`-b` command-line option).

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud (GCP), does NOT support UDP! You need to use the TCPPING JGroups mechanism to keep the cluster members connected.